# Sending data between sever and mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flexbuilder

I have to get a large amount of data from a server to a mobile application.
Currently i am passing the data in XML format which, seems to work. 
I want to know if there is another better way to do this.
Also further i may need to show the data using page views.

Note: Using Flex builder 4.6 for development of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is always a better choice when there is a data transfer between server-device. It is light-weight and easy to parse.

Comment: If you use json, you should use a library like AS3corelib (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib).

AMF will give you better performance however, but won't be as re-usable by other applications (non AS3 application).

Answer (score 1):

I personally use blazeds as server with amf-channel for the datas tr/rx...

Answer (score 0):

For large datasets, you'd better use AMF, which is a binary format that will be decoded natively by the flash player.

Depending what technololgy you use server-side, you'll need some bridge that will encode your data in AMF. (BlazeDS/GraniteDS for Java, AMFPHP for PHP, ...)